# how to encrypt data files in C++?

Tags: c++, encryption

now I am writing a app in C++, and currently my app reads models or parameters from several data files. Those files, i.e. self-define dictionary, are currently stored in plain text and to be loaded dynamically by C++ while runtime.

Yet, I don't want those files to be easily seen by my client while they get the released application, so I need to encrypt the file first. What's the general practice for this situation?

And those file are huge in size, so compile to a resource file is not a good option.

Actually I just need a **simple 'encryption', at least not plain text stored in released version**. And I dont want the encryption libraries which will load the whole file into the memory first in order to perform decryption, since the files are huge and no need to load its whole body into memory at one time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when you want to deal with encryption in C++ people tend to go for Open SSL libraries which encompass all of the functionality in a pretty standard way.

You'd have to get yourself a copy of the library and some code samples, but it's a pretty common thing and there's lots of documentation around.

Comment: I agree with @w00te, but also would like to mention that in your case, as you are using plain text files now, it could be useful to compress them before encryption (using another library, such a zlib). It will save size on disk.